# How to validate some of the inputs using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing contactList. i'm retrieving data from API. My objective is to validate name, and Phone number inputs of the contactList i.e.,in name input, it should accept only letters and for phone number also. And the form should not allow duplicate name and phone-number (it should compare with the contacts json data)

Could you please help me in this?

```
class AddContact extends Component{

constructor(){
super();
this.state = {name: '', phone:''}
}

changeHandler  = e => {
this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}

handleSubmit = e => {

const item={name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone}
 fetch('api/contacts', {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(() => {
          this.props.history.push('/contact');
        });

}
render(){

return(

         <Form>
                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Name"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />

                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Phone Number"
                    type="number"
                    name="phone"
                    value={this.state.phone}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />
                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Email"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />
              </Form>

<Button inverted color='teal' onClick={this.handleSubmit} className='saveContactbtn'>Save</Button>

);
}
}

export default AddContact;
```

API json data would be like this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "name":"asdfghjk",
      "phone":"1234567890"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "name":"qwertyu",
      "phone":"9874563212"
   }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried in the change or submit handlers to validate the inputs? I’m not seeing any logic even trying to check the values.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - Yes, I couldn't able to write logic over there. I mean i'm not sure what to write.